# XPath query does not work with pugixml

Tags: xml, c++11, xpath, libxml2, pugixml

I'm curently porting a C++ project from libxml2 to pugixml. I have an XPath query that used to work perfectly well with libxml2 but returns zero nodes with pugixml:

```
"//*[local-name(.) = '" + name + "']"
```

where `name` is the name of the elements I want to retrieve. Can anyone shed any light on what's happening?

**Code:**

```
const string path = "//*[local-name(.) = '" + name + "']";
std::cerr << path << std::endl;
try {
   const xpath_node_set nodes = this->doc.select_nodes(path.c_str());
   return nodes;
} catch(const xpath_exception& e) {
   std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
   throw logic_error("Could not select elements from document.");
}
```

**Name:**
"Page"

**XML:**

```
<MyDocument>
  <Pages>
    <Page>
      <Para>
        <Word>Some</Word>
        <Word>People</Word>
      </Para>
    </Page>
    <Page>
      <Para>
        <Word>Some</Word>
        <Word>Other</Word>
        <Word>People</Word>
      </Para>
    </Page>
  </Pages>
</MyDocument>
```

Comment: Well you would need to post samples allowing others to reproduce the problem so we need to see a minimal XML sample input and a minimal snippet of the code in the host language, without knowing what `name` is and how your input looks we can only assume that the path does not select anything in the sample you process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program works for me. Are you using the latest version of pugixml?

<s>Alternatively I did notice that pugixml isn't good with namespaces, you may need to specify them in the node name you are searching for.</s>

I just checked and it works fine with namespaces.

```
#include <pugixml.hpp>

#include <iostream>

const char* xml =
"<MyDocument>"
"  <Pages>"
"    <Page>"
"      <Para>"
"        <Word>Some</Word>"
"        <Word>People</Word>"
"      </Para>"
"    </Page>"
"    <Page>"
"      <Para>"
"        <Word>Some</Word>"
"        <Word>Other</Word>"
"        <Word>People</Word>"
"      </Para>"
"    </Page>"
"  </Pages>"
"</MyDocument>";

int main()
{
    std::string name = "Para";

    const std::string path = "//*[local-name(.) = '" + name + "']";

    pugi::xml_parse_result result;

    pugi::xml_document doc;

    doc.load(xml);

    const pugi::xpath_node_set nodes = doc.select_nodes(path.c_str());

    for(auto& node: nodes)
    {
        std::cout << node.node().name() << '\n';
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Para
Para
```